# First Chern class with sign

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, kahler-einstein-metric

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a compact Kähler manifold with Kähler form $\omega$. Furthermore, denote by $c_{1}$ the first Chern class of $M$. Assume one of the following $c_{1}>0$, $c_{1}<0$ or $c_{1}=0$. My question is the following.

**Question:** How can one show that there exists a real number $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and a Kähler form $\tilde{\omega}$ such that $\lambda \tilde{\omega} \in c_{1}$?

Greetings,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Demailly, **Complex Algebraic and Differential Geometry**, p.333. By definition,  the first Chern class of a vector bundle is positive (negative, zero) if it is positive (negative, zero) as a cohomology class, i.e. representable by some positive (negative, zero) $(1,1)$-form, i.e. a closed $(1,1)$-form which is positive (negative, zero) on any complex line in the tangent space. If positive (negative), we can take $\lambda=1$ ($\lambda=-1$) and that form as $\tilde\omega$; the manifold $M$ need only be a compact complex manifold, not necessarily Kaehler. If zero, we can take $\lambda=0$ and any Kaehler form as $\tilde\omega$, but we must then assume that $M$ is Kaehler.

Comment: But what is the $\lambda$? In particular, when $\tilde{\omega} = 0$. In this case, this is not a Kähler form!